# Jmeter OS Process sampler is not executing in bash mode

Tags: bash, docker, jmeter, performance-testing

My scenario is like, Initially i need to connect to a server through ssh command. once i connected to it enter into bash mode by typing 'bash' command then need to execute few more commands.

I have used Os Process sampler to do this and executed in docker container

Issue 1:) Getting "pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal" error while doing ssh to that particular server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41DQh.png)

Issue 2:-) Failed to execute the command in bash mode
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYGIp.png)

Can you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

If your "ssh" command assumes entering the password - you won't be able to achieve this because the password has to be supplied interactively.

If you need to execute a command (or several commmans) on the remove machine over SSH connection it's better to consider using [SSH Command sampler](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) (can be installed as a part of the **SSH Protocol Support** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Once the plugin is installed you can use it for executing your commands over SSH channel:

[image]

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks for the quick info.. But my framework supports only Os Process sampler to do this.